# Access token claims not set in environment apache mod _auth_openidc

Tags: mod-auth-openidc

Team
Im using mod_auth_openidc module in apache httpd for openauth\openid authentication. I get both id_token and access_token from OP. Claims in id token are set in environment as well as in header.  But claims in access token are not resolved. I see the encrypted access token in the header oidc_access_token but the claims are not resolved. I have configured userinfo endpoint which is supposed to resolve the claims in access token but its not happening. Appreciate your help.